# Httponly cookie is not set on cross subdomain

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, httponly, cookie-httponly

I have created 2 herokuapps, both sharing the herokuapp.com as the main domain, however when I want to set cookie from one to another it does not allow me, I also tested this with ngrok and the result is the same.

It returns **"This Set-Cookie was blocked because its Domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url"**

here is my backend code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: [process.env.FRONT_URL], // {my-frontend}.herokuapp.com
    methods: ["GET", "PUT", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization", "x-csrf-token"],
    credentials: true,
    maxAge: 600,
    
    exposedHeaders: ["*", "Authorization"],
  })
);

app.get(
  "/protect-me",
  function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.cookies["access_token"] == "accesstoken") next();
    else return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
  },
  function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({ msg: "user get" });
  }
);


app.post("/login", function (req, res, next) {
  res.cookie("access_token", "accesstoken", {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 3600 * 1000 * 24 * 180 * 1), //second min hour days year
    secure: true, // set to true if your using https or samesite is none
    httpOnly: true, // backend only
    sameSite: "none", // set to none for cross-request
    domain: process.env.COOKIE_DOMAIN, // tested both with .herokuapp.com & herokuapp.com
    path: "/"
  });

  res.json({ msg: "Login Successfully" });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log("CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80");
});
```

then on frontend I first try to login with codes below from {my-frontend}.herokuapp.com:

```js
fetch('https://{my-backend}.herokuapp.com/login', {
  method: 'POST', credentials: 'include'
});
```

and then making the second request from {my-frontend}.herokuapp.com:

```js
fetch('https://{my-backend}.herokuapp.com/protect-me', {
  credentials: 'include'
});
```

Thank you in advance for your attention :)

### Additional Note

Just as a side note, this works perfectly fine when we have a root domain and subdomain communication, what I mean is, if for example your auth server is on `yourdomain.com`, then your dashboard is on dashboard.yourdomain.com, then you can easily set a `.yourdomain.com` cookie and all works fine

but it is not possible for me to make a cookie with `auth.yourdomain.com` for `.yourdomain.com` so that the `dashboard.yourdomain.com` can access it as well

Comment: were you able to get this to work? I'm currently faced with the same scenario?

Comment: Hey @Eazy, for me the way that it worked was not very satisfactory, I could make the auth server part of sub.mydomain.com and then that domain could only handle *.sub.domain HTTP only cookies (for some browsers sibling domains will also work but not always) so in other words, if you want this to work for you, handle cookies with auth.domain.com and then put your spa on app.auth.domain.com but it was very undesirable for me so I went for a different stack. Hope this comment be helpful for you and sorry for late response

Comment: thanks for the response, in my case I was handling both web and mobile (RN apps for iOS and Android), I had to set the origin to a wildcard (*), the domain to the root (example.com), and it worked as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cookie domain should be same as that of frontend url thats what the error is also saying

Comment: Hey thank you for your comment, you are right but subdomains should also work like this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain